# FBSession must be specified

Tags: facebook-sdk-3.1, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

While trying to use FacebookSDK in an iOS app, I get this message:

> FBSDKLog: Error for request to endpoint ‘123654789?fields=name,supports_attribution,supports_implicit_sdk_logging,gdpv4_nux_enabled,gdpv4_nux_content':
>   An open FBSession must be specified for calls to this endpoint

Why exactly do I get this?

I took the code from `HelloFacebookSample` provided with the FacebookSDK and put it into my app, but I must have missed some critical part.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using Graph API v2.0. 
As the sample code is from older version, it is showing this error.

In the upgraded version the "/me/friends" endpoint no longer includes the full list of a person's friends. You need to add access token to make requests. Here is the [link to the changes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api) in v2.0

You can use the recently updated [iOS-howtos](https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-howtos) for reference

Comment: Googling FacebookSDK brought me here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios (v3.16.1)
I presume this is the last version of FacebookSDK.
I never worried about which version of Graph API I was using.
(Actually was not aware of this Graph API)
But I am not sure where to start anymore.

Comment: You can use the recently updated sample code link I posted in my answer. Else you can use [This link](https://github.com/kiran5232/kFacebook) for a differenet sample code.

Comment: OK. I don't quite understand why this developers.facebook.com/docs/ios is not a proper source of information. But thanks for your tips anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In your application's *-Info.plist change "FacebookAppID" - "123654789".

Replace the temporary ID with your application ID.